# Will updating Azure Search Documents update my Database if using a View

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-cognitive-search

We are implementing Azure Search instance for a large application. The data we are searching on is complicated and spread over many tables, and consolidated into a view in an Azure SQL database which has been indexed, a recommendation from a Microsoft representative for our particular scenario. The search results are therefore taken from a view as opposed to individual tables themselves.

Will updating a document then, additionally update the database? This is not so straightforward because it's a view, not a table. Or will updating need to take place in parallel, document and table?

Thanks!

Comment: You can update a table through a view, but there are limitations. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/modify-data-through-a-view?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will updating a document then, additionally update the database? This
>   is not so straightforward because it's a view, not a table. Or will
>   updating need to take place in parallel, document and table?

If by `document` you mean document in the index, then updating the document in Search Service index will have no impact on the database.

The flow of data between a data source (SQL Database in your case) and an index is one way and that is from data source to the index. Any updates done at the index level will not make any changes to the data source which is used to populate the index.